# here my code if to navigate the files and copy if exist the files

Tags: c#

I'm having an error so please help me.

The error:

`1 expected catch or finally`

The code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string sourceDir = @"c:\source";//folder directory path//

            try
            {
                var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".bmp") || s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".gif") || s.EndsWith("jpeg"));//identify extension name//

                foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
                {
                    string fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);
                    Directory.GetFiles(currentFile, Path.GetExtension(fileName));
                    Directory.GetFiles(currentFile, Path.GetFileName(fileName));
                    Directory.GetFiles(currentFile,  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}//get files//
```

Comment: `expected catch or finally` - expect the answers to tell you to add a `catch` or a `finally`.

Comment: Please better formulate your question title

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your `catch{}` block in your [try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add catch block end of the Try block

```
 try
    {

        var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".bmp") || s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".gif") || s.EndsWith("jpeg"));//identify extension name//


        foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
        {
            string fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);
            Directory.GetFiles(currentFile, Path.GetExtension(fileName));
            Directory.GetFiles(currentFile, Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            Directory.GetFiles(currentFile,  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));

        }  
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        //TODO Something

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a catch block

```
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    string sourceDir = @"c:\source";//folder directory path//


    try
    {

        var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".bmp") || s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".gif") || s.EndsWith("jpeg"));//identify extension name//


        foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
        {
            string fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);
            Directory.GetFiles(currentFile, Path.GetExtension(fileName));
            Directory.GetFiles(currentFile, Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            Directory.GetFiles(currentFile,  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));

        }  
    }
    catch(Exception ex) // Added
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `catch` block

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
static void Main()
 {
        string sourceDir = @"c:\source";//folder directory path//

    try
    {
        //code here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //if an error occurs with in the try block, it will handled here.
    }
}
```